# Test if GeoIP is enabled and working correctly?

Tags: geo-location

Is there an easy way to test if GeoIP is enabled and working correctly?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, if xDB is disabled then how are you testing for GeoIPs?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to setup a test file to test if the GeoIp service is working correctly.  I'd recommend following `Solution 3` in the Sitecore support issue below:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498

Basically you need to drop code like the following on your server.  Ideally in a location under the /sitecore path to protect just anyone from accessing the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestIp.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var w = LookupManager.GetInformationByIp(TextBox1.Text);
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            ListBox1.Items.Add("IP: " + TextBox1.Text);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("AreaCode: " + w.AreaCode);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("BusinessName: " + w.BusinessName);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("City: " + w.City);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Country: " + w.Country);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Dns: " + w.Dns);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Isp: " + w.Isp);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Latitude: " + w.Latitude);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Longitude: " + w.Longitude);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("MetroCode: " + w.MetroCode);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("PostalCode: " + w.PostalCode);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Region: " + w.Region);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Url: " + w.Url);
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="229px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="GetInformartionByIP" Width="234px" />

        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="314px" Width="557px"></asp:ListBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. i tried solution #3 but i am getting the following error "Null ids are not allowed. Parameter name: endpoint". xdb is disabled but GeoIp should still be working.

Comment: Naim, your question asks if there is a way to test if Geo IP is enabled and working. I believe this answer adresses this question, don't you?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes but still did not solve my problem, i am still not sure whats wrong with the GeoIp for the site in hands. the sitecore testing page is throwing an exception too.

Answer (score 2):

although Dylan's answer is correct but I would like to add few more points here -

if you still receiving incorrect information?

- Check whether the correct IP information is stored in the Analytics database

  ```
  Sitecore 7.5 – Sitecore 8.x: the “GeoIps” collection, Collection database (MongoDB)
  Sitecore 6.4.1 – Sitecore 7.2: the “GeoIps” table, Analytics database (SQL)
  ```
- If incorrect Geo location information stared for a given IP, deleted
  that incorrect IP info from the GeoIps table/collection and do an IIS
  reset.

  ```
  You have to change the IP address into hash format.
  ```
- Check correct Geo information will be cached/stored again in the next
  request

Comment: I will note this is something that he should look into if he finds that what I describe above is returning valid data.  Because GetInformationByIP will make a direct request to the Geo IP Provider and will not use the various caching and analytics data storage methods that you are describing above.  But good information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but the xdb is disabled.