# System.InvalidOperationException: geoIpServiceUri

Tags: configuration, geo-location

I am troubleshooting why GeoIP information is not being resolved in my Sitecore 9.1.1 instance on Azure PaaS

To try and ascertain whether the Sitecore GeoIP services has been subscribed to correctly, I followed the steps outlined here - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8379/73 - and proceeded to try and lookup an IP address on the server in question.

It fails me with this.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   geoIpServiceUri
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: geoIpServiceUri
```

And the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: geoIpServiceUri]
   Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider.RequestGeoIpService(String ip) +264
   Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(String ip) +313
   Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.LookupManager.GetInformationByIp(String ip) +53
   ASP.sitecore_admin_testip_aspx.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +141
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5445
```

I've narrowed it down to being something related to the Discovery Endpoint resolution. I'm just not sure where said geoIpServiceUri is supposed to be configured or where to look next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, so turns out this is a case of a very unhelpful exception message, for something that really is rather simple.

The client had not [activated the GeoIP Location service](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/setting-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html#UUID-a93a5663-aa38-1d7c-ee51-d9c209c138a8_N1542749171750) correctly, which led to the above exception being thrown - even from my TestIP code. Once this was sorted out, the error went away.

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem here. 2 solutions to this problem:activate the GeoIP Location service or setting the Analytics.PerformLookup to false.  
I was following documentation of Sitecore to configure multiple CD servers which mentions configuring that setting to true. But that should only be done when GeoIP has been activated.  
Documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/install-multiple-content-delivery-instances.html

Comment: How had the client activated it *incorrectly*? What did you do to resolve this?

Comment: Well they hadn't at all. Resolution is to get whoever is authorised, to go to the App Center and enable the service.

Comment: Ha! Well, that could be true for us, too. First I have to get access to our client's app center, though - their administrator left (without handing over the credentials...)